# php array operations with indexes

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have a array what I'm fetching with mysql query per row, each containing the same indexes and it looks as it follows

```
array(

    0=> array(
         'order_nr'=> 123,
         'order_date' => '2013-01-29 00:00:00',
         'prod_name' => 'prod_1',
         'prod_value' => 1200

       )

    1=> array(
         'order_nr'=> 123,
         'order_date' => '2013-01-29 00:00:00' ,
         'prod_name' => 'prod_2',
         'prod_value' => 2100
    )

)
```

I would like to merge theme and make the sum of prod_value and creating a new array on prod_name and at the end I would have singe array. How would I do this in php or what would be the best workaround in this case

```
array(
 'order_nr'=> 123,
 'order_date'=>'2013-01-29 00:00:00',
 'prod_name'=> array('prod_1', 'prod_2')
 'prod_value' => 3300

)
```

Comment: At least to me, isn't easy to understand what you're trying to obtain. Please, be more specific and use an "output sample"

Comment: if you're trying to sum up these values, I'd suggest to use `GROUP BY` on the database side, not on the PHP side

Comment: what is your prod_value ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of products doesn't have to be an array you can use Mysql and aggregating functions. It would be something like this:

```
SELECT order_no, order_data, GROUP_CONCAT(prod_name SEPARATOR ',') as prod_name, 
    SUM(prod_value) as prod_val FROM Products WHERE ... GROUP BY order_no;
```

If you need the product names as arrays you can then explode the string:

```
explode(',', $row['prod_name']);
```

Comment: and how would I do the concat if I want to select all the columns?

Comment: I think this would be the most elegant shortcut

Comment: It will also be more efficient than making loops in the code. I don't quite understand the question in the first comment. What do you mean you want select all the columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
$aReturn = array();

foreach( $aData as $entry ) {
 if( empty($aReturn[$entry['order_nr']]) ) {
  $entry['prod_name'] = (array) $entry['prod_name'];
  $aReturn[$entry['order_nr']] = $entry;

  continue;
 }

 $aReturn[$entry['order_nr']]['prod_name'][] = $entry['prod_name'];
 $aReturn[$entry['order_nr']]['prod_value'] += $entry['prod_value'];
}
```

This will group by `order_nr`

Comment: let me try this seems to be interesting

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array(0=> array(
                         'order_nr'=> 123,
                         'order_date' => '2013-01-29 00:00:00',
                         'prod_name' => 'prod_1',
                         'prod_value' => 1200

                       ),
            1=> array(
                         'order_nr'=> 123,
                         'order_date' => '2013-01-29 00:00:00' ,
                         'prod_name' => 'prod_2',
                         'prod_value' => 2100
                    )

            );

$sigle_arr = array();   
foreach($arr as $val){
   $sigle_arr[$val['order_nr']]['order_nr']     = $val['order_nr'];
   $sigle_arr[$val['order_nr']]['order_date']   = $val['order_date'];
   $sigle_arr[$val['order_nr']]['prod_name'][]  = $val['prod_name'];
   $sigle_arr[$val['order_nr']]['prod_value']  += $val['prod_value'];

}
print_r($sigle_arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [array_merge_recursive()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge_recursive.asp)

that is the best option for doing it

Comment: you can not get 'prod_value' in this case, It needs to be the sum of all the product 'prod_value'

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $v){
 if(!isset($newarray['order_nr'])){ 
 $newarray['order_nr'] = $v['order_nr'];
 }
 if(!isset($newarray['order_date'])){ 
 $newarray['order_date'] = $v['order_date'];
 }
 $newarray['prod_name'][] = $v['prod_name'];

 $newarray['prod_value'] = $newarray['prod_value'] + $v['prod_value'];
}
```

Comment: what if there are two orders in the array, i mean two different 'order_nr'

Comment: the question says: same index!

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = Users::find('all', array('conditions' => array('status' => array('$elemMatch' => array('fields' => array('temp')));
foreach($whichs as $which)
{
  foreach($which['temps'] as $temp)
  {
    if($temp['_id'] == $status['temp'])
    {
    array_push($tempsArray,$temp['status']);
    }
  }
}
```